# How to turn off Git warning: could not open directory: Permission denied?

Tags: git

Currently I have a directory in my repo with the permissions `700` which is owned by the other user, therefore `git` cannot see its contents and is showing to me the warnings like such:

```
$ git status 
warning: could not open directory 'some_dir/in/my_repo/': Permission denied
```

Given that the directory is expected to have those permission bits set and the ownership is also correct, is there a way I can disable the warnings?

Comment: You can *try* listing it in `.gitignore`: an ignored directory (one that is truly ignored) is never opened-and-read. If Git is currently tracking some file(s) *within* that directory, though, you'll still have issues here.

Comment: Yep, adding it to the `.gitignore` would work, as currently I'm seeing this warning for the directory which is a backup of another dir, which is indeed in the `.gitignore`. Given that I know which dirs in my repo have strict permissions, this warning is useless and quite annoying.

Comment: @abdullahalali How could deleting the *backup* be helpful in this situation? :-/